# Why Angularjs continuously call method when send a get request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api

I am new in angularjs. I am try to send a get request to my Web-Api 2 project. But I don't understand why its continuously call my method. I am following [AngularJs $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for this.

Here is my error: 
[image]

My Code is :

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function loginCtrl($scope, $http) {
        $scope.name = function () {
            console.log("Add Call");
            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:15229/api/values' }).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).
           error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               console.log(data);
           });
        };
    }
</script>

<div lang="en" ng-app="" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    {{name()}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give enough context information for me to be sure of what you want to achieve. Especially I don't know what returns your api. So I will assume It returns the value you want to display. Your code should look more like this:

`function loginCtrl($scope, $http) {
            $scope.init = function () {
                console.log("Add Call");
                $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:15229/api/values' }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.name = data;
                    }).
               error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                   console.log(data);
               });
            };
        }`

```
<div lang="en" ng-app="" ng-controller="loginCtrl" ng-init="init()">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

You should affect $scope.name in the success callback.

name should be a variable, not a function.

And the ng-init attributes defines the method to be invoked when instanciating the controller. In this case it will invoke the init() method of your controller.